# How does a desktop python application typically get run in a isolated environment like javascript's npm package

Tags: python, desktop-application, python-venv

I am curious how a typical python desktop application gets executed with a isolated environment. I know Nodejs has npm and all the dependencies are stored under the same folder when executed. And Python has venv and the requirements.txt files available, but having to create the virtual environment feel like an extra step that can be eliminated. And that means there isn't a simple one line command equivalent of `npm start` because python requires the virtual environment to be created first. Is this the correct understanding or am I missing something??

I looked into Python venv but didn't see anything that makes creating a virtual environment and execute a python program in that virtual environment one liner.

Comment: Python **does not** require a virtual environment. You can run Python without it.

Comment: @PM  - that's not quite what OP is asking, though he does bring up virtual environments.  He's asking how you distribute a Python application with all its dependencies so that a anyone can run the application without having to install the dependencies manually via a requirements.txt into their own python enviornment.